# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

From [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> The issue of holding fair elections is largely technical. The long-term solution will likely come from us. Still, bring up these issues in meta. There is a lot of room for innovation. Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. And we are completely open to appointing **temporary Moderators** when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s human exception handler.

These are not permanent positions; after the site graduates, we'll hold [an election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) to decide the permanent moderators.

So, who should we appoint as our pro tempore moderators?

---

Some ground rules (taken from past pro tem nominations on other beta sites):

- Feel free to nominate whomever you think is deserving, including yourself:

  > **Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged**. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I'm interested. Let my record speak for itself.”

  - [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)
- If someone else nominates you, *please indicate whether you accept your nomination or not*. This makes it easier for the Stack Exchange staff to build their list of candidates.
- Voting on your favorite (or least favorite) candidates is also helpful, although the top-voted candidates are not automatically chosen as if it were an election.

Comment: This isn't necessarily going to be a quick process, by the way; Outdoors has had [their nomination post](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/117/who-should-our-moderators-be) up for almost three weeks so far.

Comment: I would be very interested in nominating myself, as I'm both active and familiar with the SE theory of moderation. Unfortunately, I'm moving in a few days and will be job hunting in my new locale, thus cutting into the attention I can give to the site.

Answer (score 4):

When would naming moderators begin? I would be happy to serve as a mod now and in the future. I visit the site a lot and have enough free time to spend doing it. I'm also a good editor and have done lots of technical writing in the past.

Comment: Outdoors just got their moderators appointed today; they went into public beta 15 days before Sports did, according to Area 51.

Comment: OK, so based on the timing of Outdoors it sound like we might be a couple of weeks away then? I wouldn't mind seeing Sports.SE grow a little more before moderators. It still feels pretty small at ~150 questions.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think there's a definitive timetable anyway; the community staff just does it when they think a site is ready. And I heard today that they don't always even realize that a moderator nomination post exists, despite the fact that the community director himself wrote the guidelines that call for such a post.

Comment: Sometimes, it's an agonizing process of elimination, pitting candidates head-to-head in trials of skill and strength... Sometimes, we just throw darts at a board.